# Java requests in thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am stuck in this problem, I am using thread and http request to fetch data, but my method always returns either empty string or response of last request. Here is my code:

```
static String a = "";
public static String request(String request) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(request).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line, text = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text = line;
            }
            br.close();
            a = text;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }).start();
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an asynchronous call, so your `return` statement wont wait until `thread` executes as it non blocking, you can use call back to get the `string` when and ever it is ready

```
interface ResponseCallBack{
   void onResponse(String a);
   void onError(Exception e);
}
```

then pass this interface while calling your method

```
public static void request(String request, ResponseCallBack responseCallBack) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(request).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line, text = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text = line;
            }
            br.close();
            responseCallBack.onResponse(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            responseCallBack.onError(e);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Then you can consume it using

```
request("", new ResponseCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String a) {
            //here string will be available
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            //error in case something failed
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is not context in your Question to be sure that this is the problem, but one issue with your code is that you are not waiting for the thread to finish before returning the value of `a`.  So, you are *probably* returning the contents of `a` *before* the thread has stored anything in it.

In fact, this code is all a bit wrong-headed.  If you want `request(String)` to return the value retrieved from the server, the `request` calll can't complete until the after you have retrieved the data.  This is unavoidably synchronous.  Using a `Thread` to do the retrieving is actually achieving nothing.

(Using `join()` as suggested "fixes" the symptom, but doesn't the pointless of using a thread here.)

If you want this to be asynchronous, you could change `request` to return a `Future<String>` that the caller can use to get hold of the retrieved value at a later time.

And it would be simpler and (probably) more efficient if you used an `Executor` rather than creating once-time-use threads for each "request".